# How do I set a price for advertising on my website?

Tags: advertising

I have a website that I would like to advertise directly to advertisers (without using adsense, doubleclick, etc..).  How do I find out a ballpark figure of what I should ask for in terms of CPC or CPM?  Are there any published reports or averages I can refer to?  Any advice in setting/negotiating a starting point for price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [varies](http://searchenginewatch.com/3634925) greatly [from industry to industry](http://www.rexduffdixon.com/2010/05/06/the-average-cpm-rates-across-different-verticals/), country to country, and, especially CPM, from site to site. The easiest would be to see how much adWords charges for the keywords related to your site.

If I can get *X* click-thrus or ad impressions by spending *$Y* on adWords, then I'm not likely to pay more than *$Y/X* per click/impression on advertising on a website unless it's a very well known site in my industry or they have past ad performance data showing that their ad space is more effective.

Answer (score 1):

You not necessarily need to deal with CPM or CPC when it comes to direct advertising. You can work off your analytics and industry, and close a time-based deal -- like a outdoor advertising banner.

That's how [DaringFireball.net](http://daringfireball.net/feeds/sponsors/) and many others do. This is much simpler for advertisers and more predictable for you.